# Is this a valid way to force the classloader to use one version of a class over another?

Tags: java, classloader

There is a class (let's call it class A) in a library I'm using that's causing problems in the code. Class A is used by other classes in that library, which I use.

I want to make a small modification to class A and have that version be used. My strategy is to create a duplicate copy of that class with the same name and classpath, and make modifications in that duplicate. I also added a method called load() that doesn't exist in the original class A. This method is empty and doesn't do anything.

1. I call classA.load() in the beginning of my code to get my version of class A loaded instead of the original class A
2. Now, when I initialize a class in that library, which uses class A, it will be given my modified version of class A instead of the original class A

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why don't you simply subclass `class A` in your code and use it?

Comment: Or rewrite class A in the library.

Comment: So these two classes belong to the same package, but they are not in the same folder on your system? Just to be sure, can you add some details about where those two files could be located on the classpath? Since you're using classpath, I expect they are either in the unnamed module or you're using java before version 9. Is that correct?